# How to read a excel file based on partial name

Tags: python, pandas

I normally use glob function to read all files with a especific inicial part name files, but,
i need to read 1 file from a folder.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import glob as glob

data = pd.read_excel(r'(Path\ projectastra2021\ *.xlsx', sheet_name='register')
```

i try to read the documents from openpyxl and glob. No Solutions

Comment: Use `glob(YOUR_GLOB_HERE)` to give a list of matches. Then, assert there is only one match (or have a rule to select that match, eg last, first, or something like that). Using that result, read that Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `glob.glob(YOUR_GLOB_HERE)` to give a list of matches. Then, assert there is only one match (or have a rule to select that match, eg last, first, or something like that). Using that match, read the Excel file. It would look like:

```
f_list = glob.glob('/Users/NAME/Documents/data*.xlsx')
my_path = f_list[-1]  # last, use [0] for first, or order by mod date, etc etc
df = pd.read_excel(my_path)
```

As to how to write  your glob, I have no idea. Your current example isn't a valid one, because no paths start with `(` (especially when it is never closed). You will have to direct your `glob` to the proper path yourself. If on Windows, hold shift and right click to `Copy as path` and that'll do most of the work for you.